# How can I find a letter or number of an element in a list, and copy it into a different list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I just finished an exam in an intro to python course and was hung up on a couple questions that I could not find a simpler solution to.

Instructions:

in the given list of names, make a new list with the names containing a both lowercase and uppercase T.

example list: [Terry, Tommy, Sue, Karen, Kyle, Courtney, Steven, Adam, Eve]

I know I could use if/elif/else statements to extract t and T names, then add them to a new list, or make a count for them.  But I'm not sure how to go about it.

also, "given a list of grades, count how many grades 70-79 there are"

I know that it is mostly utilizing string and list manipulation, but i'm getting tied up in all the options and the cleanest way to go about it.  I am also hung up on how to avoid 67, 87, and 97.

Comment: Do you really mean both lowercase and uppercase T must be present in a name, or do you mean either of them? The latter seems more likely.

And what do you mean by "avoid 67, 87, and 97"?

Answer (score 0):

don't know if Ireally understand your question...

```
res = []
for nm in list_of_names:
    if 't' in nm or 'T' in nm:
       res.append(nm)
print(len(res), nm)
```

or

```
res = [nm for nm in list_of_names if 't' in nm or 'T' in nm] 
print(len(res), res)
```

or

```
import re

f = re.compile('^.*[tT].*$')
res = [i for i in list_of_names if f.match(i)]
print(len(res), res)
```

or

```
res = [i for i in list_of_names if 't' in i.lower()]
print(len(res), res)
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like it'd do as the solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Another possibility is to use ".lower()" and only check if 't' is in it.